# Login to jsp website using Requests

Tags: python, jsp, authentication

I have the following script:

```
import requests
import cookielib


jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
login_url = 'http://www.whispernumber.com/signIn.jsp?source=calendar.jsp'
acc_pwd = {'USERNAME':'myusername',
           'PASSWORD':'mypassword'
          }
r = requests.get(login_url, cookies=jar)
r = requests.post(login_url, cookies=jar, data=acc_pwd)


page = requests.get('http://www.whispernumber.com/calendar.jsp?day=20150129', cookies=jar)

print page.text
```

But the `print page.text` is showing that the site is trying to forward me back to the login page:

```
<script>location.replace('signIn.jsp?source=calendar.jsp');</script>
```

I have a feeling this is because of the jsp, and am not sure how to login to a java script page? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you're posting to the wrong page. If you view the HTML from your link you'll see the form is as follows:

```
<form action="ValidatePassword.jsp" method="post">
```

Assuming you're correctly authenticated you will probably get a cookie back that you can use for subsequent page requests. (You seem to be thinking along the right lines.)

Answer (score 0):

Requests isn't a web browser, it is an http client, it simply grabs the raw text from the page. You are going to want to use something like [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) or another headless browser to programatically login to a site.

Comment: This kind of login automation is probably achievable without a headless browser.